# Unable to retrieve dropdown data from database while editing in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm unable to retrieve dropdown data from database while editing form.
I'm unable to set the selected option (from database) of  tag in PHP .I'm unable to show the data from database in लेन्डस्केप टाईप dropdown box.
 Please help me.

Here is my existing code:

```
<?php
require_once "conn.php";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql5 = "select * from bps_registration_charkilla where reg_id=" . $id;
$result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result5) > 0) {
    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($result5)){ ?>

    <select name="ch_landscape_type" class="form-control"  value="<?php if (isset($row5['ch_landscape_type'])){ echo $row5['ch_landscape_type'];}?>">                                                       
         <option value="road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="road")echo 'selected' ;?>>सडक</option>
         <option value="main_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="main_road")echo 'selected' ;?>>मूख्य सडक</option>
         <option value="dead_end_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="dead_end_road")echo 'selected' ;?>>मुख्य (सडक डेड इन्ड भएको)</option>
         <option value="ghar" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="ghar")echo 'selected' ;?>>घर</option>
         <option value="land" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="land")echo 'selected' ;?>>जग्गा</option>
         <option value="school" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="school")echo 'selected' ;?>>स्कूल</option>
         <option value="temple" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="temple")echo 'selected' ;?>>मन्दिर</option>
         <option value="party_palace" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="party_palace")echo 'selected' ;?>>पार्टी प्यालेस</option>
         <option value="wall" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="wall")echo 'selected' ;?>>पर्खाल </option>
         <option value="chowk" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="chowk")echo 'selected' ;?>>चोक छ</option>
         <option value="pokhari" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="pokhari")echo 'selected' ;?>>पोखरी</option>
         <option value="river" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="river")echo 'selected' ;?>>नदि</option>
         <option value="rajkulo" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="rajkulo")echo 'selected' ;?>>राजकुलो</option>
         <option value="public_land" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="public_land")echo 'selected' ;?>>सार्वजनिक जग्गा</option>
         <option value="college" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="college")echo 'selected' ;?>>कॉलेग</option>
         <option value="gumba" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="gumba")echo 'selected' ;?>>गुम्बा</option>
         <option value="gl_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="gl_road")echo 'selected' ;?>>जी एल रोड (बाटो नखुलेको)</option>
         <option value="well" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="well")echo 'selected' ;?>>कुवा</option>
  </select>

<?php
     }
   }

}
?>
```

[Page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBVya.jpg)

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images. Also, please clarify exactly what your problem is.

Comment: In addition to that, the code in the picture merely outputs the data stored in `$row5`, you need to show HOW you obtain that data.

Comment: I have changed the question . @Nick

Comment: do you get data when using `var_dump`?

Comment: Yes , I did var_dump and it shows data 'road'. @little_coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the closing bracket in wrong place. Right answer is given below.

```
<select class="form-control" name="ch_landscape_type" id="ch_landscape_type" required value="<?php if (isset($row5['ch_landscape_type'])){echo  $row5['ch_landscape_type'];}?>">
      <option value="" selected>--Select--</option>
      <option value="road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="road"))echo 'selected' ;?>>सडक</option>
      <option value="main_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="main_road"))echo 'selected' ;?>>मूख्य सडक</option>
      <option value="dead_end_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="dead_end_road"))echo 'selected' ;?>>मुख्य (सडक डेड इन्ड भएको)</option>
      <option value="ghar" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="ghar"))echo 'selected' ;?>>घर</option>
      <option value="land" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="land"))echo 'selected' ;?>>जग्गा</option>
      <option value="school" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="school"))echo 'selected' ;?>>स्कूल</option>
      <option value="temple" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="temple"))echo 'selected' ;?>>मन्दिर</option>
      <option value="party_palace" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="party_palace"))echo 'selected' ;?>>पार्टी प्यालेस</option>
      <option value="wall" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="wall"))echo 'selected' ;?>>पर्खाल </option>
      <option value="chowk" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="chowk"))echo 'selected' ;?>>चोक छ</option>
      <option value="pokhari" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="pokhari"))echo 'selected' ;?>>पोखरी</option>
      <option value="river" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="river"))echo 'selected' ;?>>नदि</option>
      <option value="rajkulo" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="rajkulo"))echo 'selected' ;?>>राजकुलो</option>
      <option value="public_land" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="public_land"))echo 'selected' ;?>>सार्वजनिक जग्गा</option>
      <option value="college" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="college"))echo 'selected' ;?>>कॉलेग</option>
      <option value="gumba" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="gumba"))echo 'selected' ;?>>गुम्बा</option>
      <option value="gl_road" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="gl_road"))echo 'selected' ;?>>जी एल रोड (बाटो नखुलेको))</option>
      <option value="well" <?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']=="well"))echo 'selected' ;?>>कुवा</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `if` condition for `selected` keyword:

**Yours:**

`<?php if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type'])=="road")echo 'selected' ;?>`

***This should be like this:***

```
<?php 
if (!empty($row5['ch_landscape_type']) && $row5['ch_landscape_type'] == "road") echo 'selected';
?>
```

Try this.

Comment: Can I ask another question? @Pathik Vejani

Comment: I ccould not post question now. I can only post question again after 90 minutes but i need suggestion right now. Is there any option to post question? @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina if SO is not allowing you then we can't do anything. You can ask here briefly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57572297/unable-to-get-login-user-information-in-multiple-php-pages @Pathik Vejani

Comment: I need your help  @Pathik Vejani

Comment: Tomorrow I can help you.

Comment: Hello  @Pathik Vejani ! I need your help

Comment: @Prabina yes. say!

Comment: I have solved it. If again I stuck on any problem, I will ping you. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina ok. no issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807799/unable-to-start-mysql-server-on-ubuntu