# Unable to get login user information in multiple php pages

Tags: php

I want to get user information in multiple pages so that I can show and hide the information on the basis of login user in multiple pages. 
Code

```
    <?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']==1){
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;  
    $role_id=$_GET['role_id'];
        header("location:api/dashboard.php?role_id=$role_id");

}
else{
header("location:index.php");
    echo "login unsuccessful.";
}
?>
```

I could get the role_id in dashboard.php but I render master.php in every pages and I want to put the if condition codes to show and hide the contents in master.php on the basis of user login.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with this code

Comment: Show us the code of `master.php`, please.

Comment: I mean I want to get role_id in every pages when the user login. So that  I can put if condition for checking role_id and show or hide contents on the basis of role_id @Naruto

Comment: Where is the role information stored?  I notice you try and GET the information, but where are you actually trying to get it from?

Comment: When I put the if condition like this https://dpaste.de/k8bR   in master.php, I got error in another php files rendering master.php except dashboard.php because I sent role_id through url in dashboard.php only while user login .  @Praveen Kumar Purushothaman

Comment: I want to make able to create user profile and others if role_id is not equal to '4' and I want to put this condition in master.php. I get role_id from url only in dashboard.php while user login. So, I got error in other files rendering master.php. @Will

Comment: @Prabina what exactly you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `role_id` in session if it is not changing again and again, like below:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']==1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;  
    $role_id = $_GET['role_id'];
    // store here in session
    $_SESSION['roleid'] = $role_id;
    header("location:api/dashboard.php?role_id=$role_id");
} else {
    header("location:index.php");
    echo "login unsuccessful.";
}
?>
```

Comment: But I can open other pages without login . Here is code . How can I make my software secure?  @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina check for session on every page. If session is empty then redirect to login page

Comment: Thank you so much. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: I need your help. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina Yes, say!

Comment: I will post a question and tag you a link @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina ok sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57590816/unable-to-insert-data-into-database-after-form-submit-using-php-and-jquery-ajax  @Pathik Vejani

Answer (score 0):

this way you can't access $role_id from anywhere accept Dashboard because you send it only dashboard.
Put role_id in SESSION so that you can access from every page.

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login']==1){
   $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;  
   $_SESSION['role_id'] = $_GET['role_id'];
    header("location:api/dashboard.php");
}
else{
   header("location:index.php");
   echo "login unsuccessful.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you stored role id into session.  `$_SESSION['role_id'] = $_GET['role_id'];`

you can get role id to the pages after login then you can hide and show some information on the following:

```
    <?php 

    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["role_id"])){
        /*..what you want to display here...*/
    }else{
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    ?>
```

If role is not present you can redirect to index page.

Comment: Please help me. @heart hacker  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636023/unable-to-insert-data-from-dynamically-created-add-remove-fields-in-database-usi?noredirect=1#comment101724845_57636023