# Unable to insert data into database after form submit using php and jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to insert data in database after submitting form and wants to change the content of the submit button to saved. I'm able to change the contents of submit button afer submitting form but stores blank spaces in database. My form is similar to like this.
[image]

html form

```
<form id="yourForm">                                   
 <input type="text" name="building_length_in" id="building_length_in" placeholder="इन्च"class="form-control input-sm" value="" required>
 <input type="text" name="building_breadth_ft" id="building_breadth_ft" placeholder="फीट" class="form-control input-sm" value="" required>                                                                              

 <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#yourForm').submit(function(event){
        $('.submitBtn').attr('value','Saved');

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.submitBtn').attr('value','OK');
        }, 3000);

        var stuff = $('#yourForm').serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'application_save.php', 
            data:{
                'stuff':stuff,                
            }
            ,success: function( response ){
              console.log(response);debugger;
            }
        });

        //Prevents form submission
        return false;        
    });
});
```

application_save.php

```
    <?php 
    require_once "conn.php";
    $building_length_in=$building_breadth_ft="";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){    
        $building_length_in = trim($_POST["building_length_in"]);
        $building_breadth_ft = trim($_POST["building_breadth_ft"]);  
        mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_application 
                        (building_length_in,building_breadth_ft) 
                        VALUES (?, ?)";   

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss",
                                    $building_length_in,
                                    $building_breadth_ft);      
            $building_length_in= $building_length_in;
            $building_breadth_ft=$building_breadth_ft;      
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                if(!empty($reg_id)){
                    $success = "Submitted form successfully .";     
                    header("location: registration_detail.php?success=$success&id=".$reg_id);
                    exit();
                } else {
                    header("location: registration_detail.php");
                    exit();   
                }     
            }else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
        echo $success;
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }    
    ?>
```

console.log(stuff) contains following data .

```
stuff = "reg_id=74&registration_date=%E0%A5%A8%E0%A5%A6%E0%A5%AD%E0%A5%AC-%E0%A5%AA-%E0%A5%A7%E0%A5%A6&building_use_id=residential&building_category=a&building_structure_category_id=rcc&building_length_ft=4&building_length_in=4&building_breadth_ft=4&building_breadth_in=4&building_height_ft=4&building_height_in=4&building_storey=4&building_area=46666"
```

[image]

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: reg_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: registration_date in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_use_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_category in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_structure_category_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_length_ft in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_length_in in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_breadth_ft in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_breadth_in in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_height_ft in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_height_in in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_storey in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: building_area in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_set_charset() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>21</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: reg_id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bps\api\application_save.php</b> on line <b>26</b><br />
{"msg":"Something went wrong. Please try again later.","reg_id":0}
```

[image]

Comment: what's the error you are facing?

Comment: Did you check if `stuff` contains what you expect? What does the server recieve in `$_POST`? Did you try and execute the sql in `$sql` directly in the database and see if that behaves the same?

Comment: in `application_save.php` file where is `$reg_id` declared?

Comment: while your using a ajax. why are you triggering a  **header** redirection?

Comment: Get rid of `stuff` property in `data` and just pass the serialized string ....  `data:stuff,`

Comment: If you are not sure whats getting to PHP add a `print_r($_POST)` to the PHP script and look at `response` in the debugger

Comment: You can redirect to any url in AJAX, no need to do redirection in php file

Comment: I have many input fields in form. I just include two input fields in question for example.  @Pathik Vejani

Comment: It doesnot work  doing data:stuff, @charlietfl

Comment: @Prabina did you tried my answer? You can pass values in `data` in `AJAX`

Comment: I will try now. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: @Prabina make sure about `$reg_id`

Comment: I got above  data in database when I insert data but it works well when i use same code for inserting without using ajax @Pathik Vejani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your below code in `application_save.php`:

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){    
  // $building_length_in = trim($_POST["building_length_in"]);
  // $building_breadth_ft = trim($_POST["building_breadth_ft"]);      
  $temp = explode('&', $_POST['stuff']);
  $keys = array_keys($temp);
  for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
    $afterstr = substr($temp[$i], strpos($temp[$i], '=') + 1);
    $temp[strstr($temp[$i],'=',true)] = $afterstr;
    unset($temp[$i]);
  }

  $t = extract($temp); // here you can get all the posted variables like $reg_id, $registration_date, $building_use_id and so on.. 
  mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
  $sql = "INSERT INTO bps_registration_application (building_length_in,building_breadth_ft) VALUES (?, ?)";   
  if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $building_length_in, $building_breadth_ft);
    $building_length_in = $building_length_in;
    $building_breadth_ft = $building_breadth_ft;
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
      if(!empty($reg_id)){
        $data['msg'] = "Submitted form successfully .";
        $data['reg_id'] = $reg_id;
      } else {
        $data['msg'] = "Form submission could not be completed, please try again!";
        $data['reg_id'] = 0;
      }
    } else {
      $data['msg'] = "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
      $data['reg_id'] = 0;
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

***AJAX:***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#yourForm').submit(function(event){
      $('.submitBtn').attr('value','Saved');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('.submitBtn').attr('value','OK');
      }, 3000);
      var stuff = $('#yourForm').serialize();
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'application_save.php',
          data:{ stuff:stuff },
          dataType: "JSON",
          success: function( response ){
            console.log(res);debugger;
            var res = JSON.stringify(response);
            if(res.reg_id != 0) {
              window.location = 'registration_detail.php?success='+ res.msg +'&id=' + res.reg_id;
            } else {
              window.location = 'registration_detail.php?success='+ res.msg;
            }
          }
      });

      //Prevents form submission
      return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198322/discussion-on-answer-by-pathik-vejani-unable-to-insert-data-into-database-after).

Answer (score 2):

You are sending the serialized form data as a value of another property when all you want to send is the serialized string

That would make everything be inside `$_POST['stuff']` and you would need to manually decode it yourself

Change

```
data:{
  'stuff':stuff,                
}
```

To

```
data: stuff,
```

Comment: Is it also worth mentioning the use of header redirects in a AJAX API and the complete lack of a variable called `$reg_id` until it is tested ?

Comment: The form contains $_POST['reg_id'] as well as other input fields. I just include two input fields in question.  @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
data:{
    'stuff':stuff,                
}
```

To:

```
data:{
    stuff:stuff            
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add some explanation.

Comment: Quotes are irrelevant on javascript object property names

Comment: I have added more images of data that i got . Please help me. @charlietfl

Comment: @prabina I would like to know from you that my answer solved your problem or not?

Comment: No, it didn't solve my problem. I have solve it by another method.  @Mac