# Unable to start mysql server on ubuntu

Tags: mysql

[image: l on ubuntu]I have installed latest xampp version on ubuntu 18.04 .I'm unable to run mysql . I have tried by changing hostname localhost to 127.0.0.1 in config.inc.php and many other commands onterminal but doesnot work.It gives me following error when i run localhost/phpmyadmin . What could be the solution? 
Please help me.

Comment: try to stop `mysqld.exe` from the task manager and restart the server

Comment: try this if above is not working `sudo service mysql stop`

Comment: ok i will try. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: I need your help @Pathik Vejani

Comment: what kind of help?

Comment: @Pathik Vejani  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58094032/unable-to-fetch-data-from-two-tables-in-php-with-joining-the-tables?noredirect=1#comment102580358_58094032

Comment: someone have already marked as duplicate. did you try that?

Comment: Yes I tried. I change the code. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: is it worked or not?

Comment: No, I posted the error image. @Pathik Vejani

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199989/discussion-between-pathik-vejani-and-prabina).